# Using gitfs_remotes and Salt Stack formulas to provision Vagrant VM

Tags: vagrant, salt-stack, vagrant-provision

I'm trying to provision vagrant VM using salt with existing salt formulas. I've followed this presentation to get access to `gitfs_remotes`: https://github.com/borgstrom/salt-vagrant-saltconf2014/blob/master/presentation.md.

**salt/minion**

```
master: 127.0.0.1
state_verbose: False
```

**salt/master:**

```
# listen on the loopback in open mode
interface: 127.0.0.1
auto_accept: True

# use both the local roots as well as gitfs remotes
fileserver_backend:
  - roots
  - git

# map our project specific files to the local roots
file_roots:
  base:
    - /vagrant/salt/roots
pillar_roots:
  base:
    - /vagrant/salt/pillar

# setup our salt formulas as gitfs remotes
gitfs_remotes:
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/mysql-formula
```

**Vagrantfile (part):**

```
config.vm.synced_folder "salt/roots/", "/srv/salt/"
config.vm.synced_folder "salt/pillar", "/srv/pillar/"

config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
    salt.minion_config = "salt/minion"
    salt.master_config = "salt/master"
    salt.bootstrap_options = "-F -c /tmp/ -P"
    salt.run_highstate = true
end
```

**/salt/roots/top.sls:**

```
base:
  '*':
    - mysql
```

But I get the error:

> [INFO    ] SaltReqTimeoutError: after 60 seconds. (Try 7 of 7) Attempt
>   to authenticate with the salt master failed

Answer (score 2):

A masterless minion is able to use gitfs without an explicitly configured master. There was an [issue in saltstack/salt](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/6660).

Have a look at this [issue in saltstack/salt-bootstrap](https://github.com/saltstack/salt-bootstrap/issues/245), for details about why to install things in front using bash provisioning.

Here is a working configuration using the node-formula.

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"

  # mount state tree and pillar
  config.vm.synced_folder ".saltstack/salt/", "/srv/salt/", type: "rsync"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".saltstack/pillar/", "/srv/pillar/", type: "rsync"

  # install those to be able to use gitfs for node formula
  # @see https://github.com/saltstack/salt-bootstrap/issues/245
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get -y install git-core"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get -y install python-setuptools"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo easy_install GitPython"

  config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
    # Workaround for:
    # Copying salt minion config to /etc/salt
    # Failed to upload a file to the guest VM via SCP due to a permissions
    # error. [...]; @see:
    # https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5973#issuecomment-137276605
    salt.bootstrap_options = '-F -c /tmp/ -P'
    salt.masterless = true
    salt.minion_config = ".saltstack/minion"
    salt.run_highstate = true
    salt.verbose = true
  end

  # sync working dir
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync",
    rsync__exclude: [".git/", ".saltstack"]
end
```

**.saltstack/minion**

```
state_verbose: True

file_client: local

gitfs_provider: gitpython

fileserver_backend:
  - roots
  - git

gitfs_remotes:
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/node-formula.git
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting that error because when a minion connects to Salt Master - the request has to be approved by Salt master. It is like a security mechanism - first time around needs approval, second time onwards the fingerprint of machine is used. On your salt master run:

```
sudo salt-key
```

You should see something like and you will notice that the key of new machine is not yet accepted.

`Accepted Keys:
Denied Keys:
Unaccepted Keys:
xyz.hostname.com
Rejected Keys:`

Go ahead and run the command:

```
sudo salt-key -A
```

Say yes on confirmation and the key will be accepted and the error should go away. Also to test that the minion is reachable run command on master:

```
sudo salt '*' test.ping
```

This should return true from minions.

Finally use a tried and test project like [this one](https://github.com/elasticdog/salt-sandbox) from Salt team or [one I have written](https://github.com/vishal-biyani/saltstack-cluster) and you will get going with Salt quite fast.

Comment: Running manual command like this doesn't help in a vagrant environment which is supposed to run autonomously

Comment: // , I think this may not answer the question, but the configuration he's showing has a master and slave... @Dave, consider editing your question.

Comment: @Dave You can also consider writing a small state file which runs every few minutes and approves pending minion requests